# How to control spring boot rest csv response cell format?

Tags: java, csv, spring-boot

I have spring-boot rest webservice that returns csv file with number format for all its cells. Want some cell to be text.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/generateReport", produces = "text/csv")
public ResponseEntity<?> generateReport() throws Exception {
    String csvString = reportService.generateReport();
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>(csvString, HttpStatus.OK);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

I want to make some column cells format text only not number.

Comment: If you want text, put the value in quotes(")

Comment: Tried this.
Unfortunately, didn't work.

reportBuffer.append(user.getSalary() + "");